# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15

Tags: arrays, string, android-studio

I am creation a android application that consist on update question from an array onClick action. My array is a string array. When click the question will be updated.

Igot a error : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
               
                    if (mQuestionNumber == Learn.description.length - 1) {
                        mNextButton.setText("Terminer");
                    }
                    if ((mQuestionNumber > 0) && (mQuestionNumber == Learn.description.length - 1)) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(AnimActivity.this, FinalActivity.class));
                    }
                    updateQuestion();



            }
        });
  private void updateQuestion() {

        mImageView.setImageResource(Learn.images[mQuestionNumber]);
        mQuestion.setText(Learn.description[mQuestionNumber]);
        mysong = MediaPlayer.create(AnimActivity.this, Learn.audio[mQuestionNumber]);
        mysong.start();
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
```

my array:

```
 public static String[] description = new String [] {
               " Amcic",
               "Aqjun",
               "Ayaziḍ",
                "Ikerri",
                "Tafunast",
                "Tayaziḍt",
                "Taɣaṭ",
                "Abṛik",
                "Ačawčaw",
                "Aɛidiw",
                "Awtul",
               "Ilef",
                "Aɣyul",
                "Tizizwit",
               "Adandu",
        };
```

Then i got the error outofbounding

Comment: add a `return;` after `startActivity` in order to avoid calling `updateQuestion` again